# Syncing configuration files from production server to mercurial repository

Tags: rest, mercurial, devops, webhooks, mercurial-hook

We have an admin page that allows us to upload and update a configuration file on our production server. We want to maintain a record of all changes made to the configuration file, so we need to push it to the main branch of our Mercurial repository every time it is updated.

Is there a standard method or practice to automate this process of syncing the configuration file from the production server to the Mercurial repository?

Currently, we are manually pushing the file to the repository, which is time-consuming and prone to human error.

Comment: This is kind of a broad question and you haven't provided any specific detail about your system. Mercurial can be run from the command line so naturally you can script anything you want to happen.